# GeoIP Service for .NET Exception

Tags: c#, web-services, exception, geolocation, ip

I use .net service called GeoIP and I have an exception that makes me dissapointed.

Service adress: http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL

I use it very first time, so it might seems to be "click-and-watch" code, but it is not the main thing.

I have an exception when I try to get an IO or country after initalizing client.

```
        GeoIPService.GeoIP geoIp;
        GeoIPServiceSoapClient client;
        client = new GeoIPServiceSoapClient("GeoIPServiceSoap");

        geoIp = client.GetGeoIP("37.57.106.53"); // HERE IS EXCEPTION
```

Exception message text:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

at WebserviceX.Service.Adapter.IPAdapter.CheckIP(String IP)

at WebserviceX.Service.GeoIPService.GetGeoIP(String IPAddress)

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

And there is a link for printscreen: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yoq1pr7zp6qax04/geoIpEx.png?dl=0

It would be really lucky for me if someone had to use this service and know how to solve that trouble.

Thanks!

Comment: `I have an exception that makes me dissapointed` well worded, but the service seems to not answer your request. Look at the user-friendly website `http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?op=GetGeoIP` and type in the IP adress `37.57.106.53`, you see that the **server** also faults. Not a problem on your side, but the webservice is broken. When I type in my IP address, it works however - so it might just be that the server doesn't resolve **this particular** address, you're out of luck.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Hmgh, you are right. I typed some US ip adress, and then geoip service showed me the country. And as a main question, there was no exception. Web-site that you linked here (http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?op=GetGeoIP) - is it additional service for service that I use ? (Sorry for tautology)

Comment: No it's not a seperate service, it's the exact same service just with different bindings. Look at the POST examples, `POST /geoipservice.asmx HTTP/1.1`, or also with GET `GET /geoipservice.asmx/GetGeoIP?IPAddress=string `, it's going to the exact same website. Google also has a GeoIP service, there are millions of others. First google hit gives me `https://freegeoip.net/json/37.57.106.53`.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Thank you a lot! Can you suggest, how can I get data from service that you gave in exemple(https://freegeoip.net/json/37.57.106.53). It might me kind a request, I did not do similar things, so maybe you can tell me right way ?Cause service that I was going to use some sucks at many IP's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, a different GeoIP provider is needed since it doesn't resolve all host address well.

We can use http://json2csharp.com/ and feed it the JSON it gave you from that IP adress. That generates the C# class:

```
public class GeoIPInfo
{
    public string ip { get; set; }
    public string country_code { get; set; }
    public string country_name { get; set; }
    public string region_code { get; set; }
    public string region_name { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string zip_code { get; set; }
    public string time_zone { get; set; }
    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public double longitude { get; set; }
    public int metro_code { get; set; }
}
```

We download the JSON through HTTP with a `WebClient` object, then convert the string into above C# object using `Newtonsoft.JSON`. (install libary via nuget package at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/). A sample program would be:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        /* Download the string */
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string json = client.DownloadString("https://freegeoip.net/json/37.57.106.53");
        Console.WriteLine("Returned " + json);

        /* We deserialize the string into our custom C# object. ToDo: Check for null return or exception. */
        var geoIPInfo = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GeoIPInfo>(json);

        /* Print out some info */
        Console.WriteLine(
            "We resolved the IP {0} to country {1}, which has the timezone {2}.",
            geoIPInfo.ip, geoIPInfo.country_name, geoIPInfo.time_zone);

        Console.ReadLine();

        return;
     }
```

Which outputs

```
We resolved the IP 37.57.106.53 to country Ukraine, which has the timezone Europe/Kiev.
```